# Display alias of a subdomain as main domain name

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, alias, yoast

first of all thanks for being there because I don't know what I could do without Stack Overflow through all these years!

Here's the thing. I developed a Wordpress website in a subdomain comeovercome.livewithauthenticity.com

and I bought a domain alias to access the url easily

comeovercome.com

but when I use the share feature and when I setup the Yoast SEO plugin, I can't use this domain name as the main one, so in the shared post people get automatically the long real url instead of the easy one.

How can I keep the website in this subdomain but always point to it with the nice URL?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your website files into the subdirectory?

Comment: yes, all files are in a subdirectory

Comment: can you show your httacces file code here?

Comment: thanks R.K. yes here it is:

# BEGIN WPSuperCache
# END WPSuperCache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Before change anything please backup backup backup 
read the #tag comments and then change according to your domain name

## .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect

```
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

Thanks